# Python string formatting weirdness

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have an custom config class in an application and I'd like to override the defaults by reading from environment variables. I'm facing some strange behaviour with Python's `str.format()` and I'd like to understand why. This code runs successfully depending on the value of the env vars that are passed in. Here it is:

```
class Config(object):
    SQS_QUEUE = '{client}-{env}'


class ClientConfig(Config):
    ENV = os.environ.get('ENV', default='dev')
    CLIENT = os.environ.get('CLIENT', default='v')
    SQS_QUEUE = Config.SQS_QUEUE.format(client=CLIENT, env=ENV)


config = ClientConfig()
print(config.ENV)
print(config.CLIENT)
print(config.SQS_QUEUE)
```

This is my env var file:

```
export ENV="prod"
export CLIENT="r"
```

It is being loaded like so: `source .env` and I can see that the vars are set by running the env command:

```
$ env
ENV=prod
CLIENT=r
[...]
```

When I run the python code above, I would expect the SQS queue variable to be a string with value "r-prod" instead, I'm getting "-prod" which is strange considering both ENV and CLIENT are set (as I can see from the print statement)

EDIT: here's the full output

```
$ python3 test.py
prod
r
-prod
```

Comment: What is the full output of your python script? What happens if you put all the class related code into an `__init__` function?

Comment: If you are going to store all the settings as class variables, you don't need to create an instance of the class. (All instances will be identical anyway.) (It's also not clear that there's any reasons to use such a class in place of a simple dict.)

Comment: If I run this on Python 3.10, I get the output as expected (although I do not have ENV and CLIENT set on my system, I do get correctly `dev`, `v`, and `v-dev` for the respective print statements. I ran this within an iPython environment.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `ENV=prod CLIENT=r python3 tmp.py` outputs `prod`, `r`, and `r-prod` as expected. I suspect, though, that your env var file uses DOS line endings, which means both your variables end with carriage returns, which cause the output to *look* like `-prod`. (The carriage return following `r` moves the cursor to the start of the line, causing `-prod` to overwrite it.)

Comment: As can be seen, for example, with `ENV=$'prod\r' CLIENT=$'\r' python3 tmp.py`.

Comment: @PrinsEdje80 I'm running 3.7.10. What happens if you set the env vars?

Comment: mystery solved, it was the DOS line endings... Managed to fix with dos2unix. Thanks @chepner !